# Are the diodes and capacitors oriented correctly in this motor driver PCB? TMC2209 stepper motor driver

Tags: pcb-assembly

[image]

If the polarity of both diodes and both caps look right, the driver IC probably smoked because of my solder job.

[Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/TMC2209_datasheet_rev1.08.pdf#page=82):
[image]

[image]

Comment: Either my glasses are foggy, or that darn camera refuses to focus.  In any case, maybe next time you'll put designators and orientation marks (for components that should have them) on your pcb silkscreen/legend layer...

Comment: I did. I didn't make the order though. That is a different layer.

Comment: Narrowed it down to the tantalum capacitors (in green). https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/KYOCERA-AVX/TCJB337M002R0045?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsh%252B1woXyUXj8ZghLFsu50xr8d20nLNOy4%3D

Answer (score 0):

> The motor supply pins VS should be decoupled with an electrolytic capacitor (47 μF or larger is recommended) and a ceramic capacitor, placed close to the device.

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/TMC2209_datasheet_rev1.08.pdf#page=81
[image]

I was using 330uF tantalum capacitors only rated for a few volts. I should use electrolytic (rated for 50 V).